# Validación en firma electrónica XML

Tags: java, xml, signature

Estamos tratando de validar en JAVA ficheros XML que vienen "Contrafirmados" en formato XADES.

1. Priero creamos un fichero XML original que firmamos en XADES-XL utilizando las librerías de JAVA que pone a disposición el Ministerio de Industria en este enlace.
2. Si validamos este fichero firmado (con una firma única) en XADES-XL, la validación funciona correctamamente.
3. Este fichero es enviado a un segundo sistema independiente, donde ahí lo "cofirman" con otro certificado pero utilizando XADES-BES (y no sabemso que librerías utilizan).
4. El problema es que el validar este fichero XML "Cofirmado" después del paso 3, si intentamos validarlo nos falla en la validación.

El log de error que nos da es el siguiente

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="id-20176132e7fc7996186825d888c1e245"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:Signature$
5+SSBlpKbCkxNr95VPiuKXRfzdr79jUzRdUB1WqEcP33wGGjM7jkijmisj83dyGm5CumV3ULj3xa
1tmxICBl8/sz209o0e5xGvKGks0A/wtjfx7UHR
2021-02-02 09:42:07 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] internal: Pre-digested input:
2021-02-02 09:42:07 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] internal: XGUkIy3TtHQY8kyBTct6keLwUGsbhRQ13e7UZe
Sty1PSFctAYmke5ap4s4cQI881AgAw+xybMOl1SIypYA+j5NndjJv0Vjhc7IK6V7cLzifF2RqFBr
wKBTEuN7EXx5yDd81iF1AbiNU74Xjtv1uZCKPt0=</ds:Modulus><ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent></ds:RSAKeyValue></ds:KeyValue></ds:KeyInfo><ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#id-20176132e7fc7996186825d888c1e245"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xades-id-20176132e7fc7996186825d888c1e245"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2021-01-27T08:52:09Z</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert>
<xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>2mksooevK91Meei8a4JFEm6TV6A=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=ES,O=ACCV,
OU=PKIACCV,CN=ACCVCATEST-120</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>3355782527402877539580550263211431104</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignatureProductionPlace>
</xades:SignatureProductionPlace></xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SignedDataObjectProperties><xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#fe-004cc8e1-136f-4f86-8176-332140833af3"><xades:MimeType>application/octet-stream
</xades:MimeType></xades:DataObjectFormat></xades:SignedDataObjectProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object></ds:Signature>
2021-02-02 09:42:07 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] dom: Expected digest: NmZyy9ACFJOKkMKCpzrPPTJ9T+U=
2021-02-02 09:42:07 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] dom: Actual digest: mIwwNVfcGd4Icxq/8E0U9JqCLKo=
2021-02-02 09:42:07 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] dom: Reference[] is valid: false
2021-02-02 09:42:07 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] dom: Couldn't validate the References
2021-02-02 09:42:07 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] XmlValidationServiceImpl: Signature failed core validation
2021-02-02 09:42:07 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] XmlValidationServiceImpl: signature validation status: true
2021-02-02 09:42:07 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] XmlValidationServiceImpl: ref[0] validity status: true
2021-02-02 09:42:07 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] XmlValidationServiceImpl: ref[1] validity status: true
2021-02-02 09:42:07 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] XmlValidationServiceImpl: ref[2] validity status: false
```

Lo que no entendemos muy bien es que significa este

**XmlValidationServiceImpl: ref[2] validity status: false**

es decir, ¿qué nos indica para saber por donde debemos a buscar el error?.

¿Aguien nos puede dar alguna idea?

Gracias